# Import a txt file to CSV with Python (all data in 1 column)

Tags: python, csv, text-files

I have a little problem I could use some help with.
In a program I run, I need to import a .txt file in Excel 2010 and have it separated by ';' in 1 column. As of now, each time I open the resulting CSV file, no matter which syntax I try, Excel sorts my data in separate columns.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem and found a solution?

Your help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate, what does the formatting of the file you are trying to import look like and what do you want it to look like when you import it in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

So here is my code so far :

```
import os
import csv

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Contractuel\Desktop\Test')

with open('Setback.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(";") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('TESTS.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

However, I end up getting this :

[Result I get from my code :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJzBS.png)

and I would need something like this :

[What I would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trUiE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

```
import glob
import csv
import xlwt

for filename in glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.txt"):
    spamReader = csv.reader((open(filename, 'rb')), delimiter='|',quotechar='"')
    encoding = 'latin1'
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding=encoding)
    sheet=xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wb.add_sheet('sheet 1')
    newName = filename
    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowx, colx, value)
    wb.save(newName.replace('.txt','.xls'))
```

Or, this.

```
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

for filename in glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.txt"):
    spamReader = csv.reader((open(filename, 'rb')),
                            delimiter='|', quotechar='"')

    newName = filename.replace('.txt', '.xlsx')

    workbook = Workbook(newName, {'strings_to_numbers': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            worksheet.write(rowx, colx, value)

    workbook.close()

print "Done"
```